# Bootstrap flip animation height 2px

Tags: css, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a flip card on my site but everytime I make the elements they default to a height of 2 or 1 px. I believe it has something to do with making the position of a couple of the elements absolute, but that is the only way I've seen to do this without messing up the layout of my page. I'm using Bootstrap CSS and some custom CSS and JS Here is my code:
HTML:

```
           <div class="scene col-md-4 d-inline-block h-50">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="face front">
                        <img src="images/pawprints_edit.png" width="300" height="180" alt="sign up for al-van newsletter" id="news-img" class="d-inline-block col-md-12 img-fluid h-50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="face back">
                        <form action="form-to-email.php" method="post" name="mail-form" class="mail-form">
                            <label for="name">Name:</label><br/>
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required width="25"><br/>
                            <label for="email">Email Address:</label><br/>
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com" required width="50">
                            <label for="message">Please type your message:</label><br/>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="4">Please sign me up for the Paw Prints Newsletter.</textarea><br/>
                            <input type="button" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* form animation */

.scene {
    width: 33.3333333%;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front {
    background: #98b98a;
}

.back {
    background: #4c87a9;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.is-flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* End animation */
```

Any help would be appreciated. Perhaps there is a workaround? It displays correctly and the animation works in a way if I remove "position: absolute" but that section is introduced into the flow of the page and the layout doesn't work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to apply `!important` to the height property and it was recognized before whatever bootstrap property was forcing the absolute elements to be only 2px in height.

Answer (score 0):

I set a hover on your card and it appears to work.

```
.card:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I need it to flip on click and am handling that with JS. The animation works fine but in order to get any height I have to remove position absolute and that makes the front and back stack instead of occupy the same space in the page flow. I need a workaround for the absolute position. I tried defining height explicitly but it didn't have any effect

Comment: So bootstrap is affecting the container.Try moving the 'scene' class to the end? col-md-4 d-inline-block h-50 scene -- order or inline style the element height. Hard to tell without setting up the bootstrap as well here or a sample page. Does adding an !important to the height have any effect?

Comment: That didn't have any noticeable effects.

Comment: However, when I applied !important to the width, it worked. Thank you.